# Lucene's query does not find expected results

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I want to find a given file name in a bunch of shell files by using Lucene.net. Here's my index building method:

```
public void BuildIndex(string dir, string pattern, Encoding enc = null)
{
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(dir)) {
        throw new DirectoryNotFoundException(dir);
    }

    foreach (string file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(dir, pattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(file, enc ?? Encoding.Default))
        {
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.Add(new Field("File", Path.GetFileName(file), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("LineText", line, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            writer.AddDocument(doc);
        }
        if (FileIndexed != null) {
            FileIndexed(file);
        }

    }
    writer.Optimize();
    writer.Dispose();
    luceneIndexDirectory.Dispose();
}
```

The `BuildIndex` method indexes all of the shell files in `dir` directory, by using LukeNet I could load the index files and perform some queries.

When I use `A.FNTAQ01D` as search expression, both LukeNet and my program can find this line:
`export  MQRCV=$DD_PATH/DASD/A.FNTAQ01D`
but not this line:
`ASCC00464FSTEP140 OLD$DD_PATH/DASD/COMD89_A.FNTAQ01D`
Why is that?

(I use StandardAnalyzer, maybe I miss something about it?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, standard analyzer creates for you first line these tokens:

```
export
mqrcv
dd
path
dasd
a.fntaq01d
```

And for your second line these:

```
ascc00464fstep140
old
dd
path
dasd/comd89_a.fntaq01d
```

On search, `A.FNTAQ01D` is converted to `a.fntaq01d` which only occurs on your first line.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! But why does `dasd/comd89_a.fntaq01d` in second line NOT splitted by `/`?

Comment: And how can I hit the second line by using `A.FNTAQ01D`?

Comment: The StandardAnalyzer is quite comlpex. It uses the StandardTokenizer which says: "Splits words at hyphens, unless there's a number in the token, in which case the whole token is interpreted as a product number and is not split." I think the same holds for slashes. I recommend you to use an other/custom analyzer. Maybe the SimpleAnalyzer is enough for your need and you dont have to write your own analyzer.

Comment: @faith I've tried SimpleAnalyzer, but it seems to split `A.FNTAQ01D` to `a` and `fntaq01d`, which causes even the 1st line can't be found. I have to look at the custom analyzer, thank you anyway!

Comment: It very important that you use the same analyzer for indexing(!!) and searching! even when you write your own custom analyzer.